# Managed Object Context saves only last record of managed objects loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm importing large set of data using `NSOperation` subclass and save it like this:

```
 - (void)main
{

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addPort:[NSPort port] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self persistentStoreCoordinator]];
[moc setUndoManager:nil]; //to make the import more effecient
NSError *error; 

for (NSManagedObject *taskInfo in self.tasks) { //self.tasks are the xml returned from a web service

 Task *taskDB  = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Task"inManagedObjectContext:moc];
        taskDB.taskID = [taskInfo valueForKey:@"TaskID"];
        taskDB.taskAssignedDate = [taskInfo valueForKey:@"TaskAssignDate"];
        taskDB.corporate = [self getCorporate:moc :[[taskInfo valueForKey:@"FacilityInfo"] valueForKey:@"ID"] ]; 
        taskDB.dateTime = [[NSDate date]retain];
        taskDB.requestNumber = [taskInfo valueForKey:@"RequestNumber"];


 ... //there are a lot of other properties for the task table
 } //for
 [moc save:&error];

 [moc reset];
 [pool drain], pool = nil;

 }
```

but the `managedObjectContext` only saves the last record in the loop and does not save all records, however, if I put the saving code inside the loop, the `managedObjectContext` will save all records as it is supposed to do. I also tried to do the save after some number of records by setting a counter in the loop to do a save after (10) records, but same problem occurs, the `moc` saves one record after every 10 loop runs. how can I solve this problem ? I want the `moc` to save **all records** at once or every 10 loop runs .

thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Why are you calling reset in on your `NSManagedObjectContext`? This will reset the context to it's base state.

Comment: because i use it in another place in this class (in the main method)

Comment: Do you merge the two `ObjectContext`?

Comment: there is only one managed object context, there is no merge.

Comment: But in this operation you create a new one, thus there must be an other one some where. That will be the one the which is in the app delegate most of the time.

Comment: oh you are right, there is a managedObjectContext in the appDelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do, is merge the context to the one in you appdelegate. 
First register the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(contextChanged:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];
```

Place this some where in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method.

And add this method:

```
- (void) contextChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if( [notification object] == [self managedObjectContext] ){
        return;
    }

    if( ! [NSThread isMainThread] ){
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(contextChanged:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
        return;
    }

    [[self managedObjectContext] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];      

    //You could save here:
    NSError *error = nil;
    if(! [[self managedObjectContext] save:&error] ) {
        NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@", error);
    }

}
```

What happens now it that, wehen you save the ObjectContext from an other thread you appdelegate will be notified that an objectcontext has been saved.  Next you check wheter it is not the some context as the one in you appdelegate, then make sure you run in the main thread and merge the context from the notification.

---

Small other think weird in your code: `taskDB.dateTime = [[NSDate date]retain];`. There is no need to retain the date, the property should either copy or retain the date for you.

Comment: I have put this code in the app Delegate but no difference does it make .. same problem still exists ... only the last record is saved when I do the save after finishing the loop.

Comment: I placed an NSLog in the contextChanged method to enure it's working properly and it was ok.

Comment: I noticed something important, all the records are saved in the sqlite DB but the displayed one (in the tableView) is only the last record, so I think I have to refresh the context somehow so that the tableView displays all of the saved records.

Comment: Use a [`NSFetchedResultsController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the tableview, this controller can inform you if there are new objects.

Comment: It worked.. thank you so much. about the date retain, if i didn't retain the date here the app will crash although it's retained in the @property line in .h file.

Comment: Just make sure that you do not leak it, you can check with the leaks profiler to see if it is leaking. Maybe you over release it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Check after each "[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName " if the size of [moc insertedObjects] is changing.

And check if you don't get a low memory until save context is called.

Comment: I have NSLog'ed the number of inserted objects, every loop the console displays 1 or 2 only ... so weird...